# Throwing custom error messages in java struts

Tags: java, struts

Are there any useful patterns or best practices about throwing/showing User friendly error messages in Struts 1?

```
if(something nasty...) {
    throw new UserException("very bad thing happened");
} else if(something other nasty...) {
    throw new UserException("other thing happened");
} .... other 100 cases
```

Because using the above sample in the validate() method over and over again seems a bit redundant and unprofessional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create ActionMessage(s) and display these.
There is better information here than I can give you:
http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-logic-messages-present-logic-messages-notpresent-example/